# The beautiful captive vs. self-pleasure

Tags: sexuality, army-military-war

If a soldier is in battle and meets an attractive woman, there is a dispensation for him to have her. Opinions differ as to whether he can rape her or whether it must be consensual, and how many times he can do it.

All of these interpretations are still relatively extreme forms of behavior. Why does the dispensation go to this extreme without first stopping at less extreme forms of behavior such as masturbation?

Wouldn't it be less destructive for the soldier to try masturbating to sate his desires before having sex with a strange woman?

Comment: Please a) clarify the question, b) cite sources, c) consider rephrasing in terms respectful of your audience and _halacha_.

Comment: The answer is probably that those other options wouldn't satisfy him sufficiently.

Comment: so supposing it would, would the soldier be allowed to take this intermediate action?

Answer (score 2):

The teshuvos Maharsham (7:26) quotes the Zohar that masturbation is worse than all other sin.  The teshuvos P'nei Yehoshua says that it is like murder.  The Maharal in Be'er HaGula (Be'er sheni perek tes) says that it is worse than murder.

In contrast, being with the "strange woman" is probably not considered "wasting seed" - they could have a child and this would at least constitute לשבת יצרה - see תוס' גיטין מא א ד"ה לישא.

So this would be a lesser sin than masturbation.

Comment: I don't like it, but at least is an answer.

Here is why I don't like it:
I recall something from Megillat Ruth that Ploni Almoni's faliure to redeem his family was so bad that his name was withheld from the narrative and Ploni Almoni was used instead. I contrast, Onan's name is left in.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Ploni Almoni is mentioned - his name is Tov.  He is only not mentioned after he neglects to redeem his family.  Er and Onan are also not mentioned after their sin.

Comment: actually, they are. Bamidbar 26:19.  The fact that Ploni's real name is alluded to before is sin only strengthens my point.

Comment: @ClintEastwood They are named in recounting lineage.  They are not named again in the story.  Tov does not come up again anywhere else in Tanach, so there really isn't any indication from Bamidbar 26.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Additionally, Ploni Almoni being left out is not necessarily indicative of the severity of the sin, rather the nature of the sin.  He failed to continue the name of his family, so his own name was erased.

Comment: 1. How else could they be mentioned in the story? They died!
2. Is Tov's name actually mentioned or is it merely inferred, highlighting the conspicuous absence of his name?
3. Onan's sin also involved not continuing the name of his kin's family! Why was his name not also erased given the nature of his sin?

Comment: @ClintEastwood 1. In verses 9 and 11, it refers to Er as "brother" instead of Er, which could have been used.  2. Tov's name is mentioned explicitly.  3. That question would equally apply to your own point, but the answer I would say is that his name doesn't appear again in the story, he is replaced by "brother"

Comment: 1. Er may be replaced by "brother", Onan is not. Perhaps "brother" is used to emphasize the responsibility to perform a levirite marriage? 2. Where is Tov's name mentioned explicitly? That his name is Tov is only mentioned in the gemara which Rashi quotes. i.e. it is only a remez (or deeper)

Comment: @ClintEastwood 1. please revisit verse 11, which refers to "brothers" plural of shelah - who are those _multiple_ brothers? 2. See Rus 3:13.

Comment: Using brother or brothers in those circumstances is not so unusual compared with using Ploni Almoni. With Er and Onan, the reader knows who the word brothers refer to. With Ploni Almoni, the reader can't tell who that person is. To obscure the person's identity in such a blatant way is noteworthy.

Comment: @ClintEastwood So why isn't Onan omitted for the same sin that Ploni Almoni did? (In any case, I think the simplest answer is what I said before - his name is not erased because of severity - it is a reflection of what he did.  Idol worshipers and murderers in Tanach do not have their names erased)

Comment: To rephrase: because Onan's sin was less severe than Ploni's sin? You said earlier that Ploni being left out was not due to severity!

Comment: @ClintEastwood "because Onan's sin was less severe than Ploni's sin?" - they did the same sin that you say is worth being left out for - not redeeming family.  "You said earlier that Ploni being left out was not due to severity! " - I know, and I stand by that.  You didn't seem to accept that, and I proceeded accordingly.

Comment: Excellent. So if Ploni's sin is more severe than Onan's sin (which I call aggravated masturbation due to the additional factors), how can we say that masturbation is worse than any other sin per your original answer?

Comment: @ClintEastwood Onan did the same thing and more than Ploni!  He _ALSO_ did not continue his family.  So Ploni _CANNOT_ be worse.  That is what I am trying to point out to you.  I suggested that Onan would also not be mentioned again had it been relevant in the story, you can take it or leave it.  But do you think Ploni was worse than Esav who murdered, violated a betrothed woman, and denied G-d's existence, and still has his name mentioned throughout?  Doesn't seem name deletion results from being really bad.

Comment: @ClintEastwood I don't know how you answer this issue. I think it all makes sense - Ploni, who the _only_ thing he did was failure to redeem his family, and even that was out of concern for a forbidden union (he thought Rus was assur to marry, see mefarshim there, e.g. Malbim), the Torah had to identify for us what his failure was.  Others, who did much worse, did not need that emphasized.